# How do you target a non-standard html tag with xpath?

Tags: php, xpath

```
$html = '<g-review-stars><span class="Fam1ne EBe1af" aria-label="Rated 4.7 out of 5," role="img"><span style="width:63px"></span></span></g-review-stars>';

 $doc = new DOMDocument;
 $doc->loadHTML($html);
 $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
 $node= $xpath->query('//g-review-stars[]' 
 )->item(0);
 $html = $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($node); //
 print_r($html);
```

In my understanding, there's no way to do this, so I was wondering if there's some kind of hack. The problem is that Google doesn't use any specific id in their div tags that wraps the g-review-stars, so it's hard to target it.

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag g-review-stars invalid in Entity, line: 1
in C:\Sources\modules\test-pregmatch\script.php on line 6

Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in C:\Sources\modules\test-pregma
tch\script.php on line 8

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function item() on boolean in C:\S
ources\modules\test-pregmatch\script.php:9
```

I am expecting to target the html node g-review-stars and I am expecting `'<g-review-stars><span class="Fam1ne EBe1af" aria-label="Rated 4.7 out of 5," role="img"><span style="width:63px"></span></span></g-review-stars>'` as an output.

Comment: What exactly are your trying to do? What is your expected output?

Comment: I am expecting to target the html node g-review-stars and I am expecting '<g-review-stars><span class="Fam1ne EBe1af" aria-label="Rated 4.7 out of 5," role="img"><span style="width:63px"></span></span></g-review-stars>' as an output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$node= $xpath->query('.//g-review-stars');
echo $doc->saveHTML($node[0]);
```

Output:

```
<g-review-stars>
      <span class="Fam1ne EBe1af" aria-label="Rated 4.7 out of 5," role="img">
      <span style="width:63px">
      </span>
      </span>
   </g-review-stars>
```